# Fill 'n' cells in Excel by reading the value of n

Tags: vba, excel

I want to read the value of any no. (4 or 5 or..) from one of the cell (say B2) and fill those no. of cells at a particular location (say b11, b12, b13, b14)...
If I do not fill then it should give a msg "please fill the fields".
Also those fields should be marked with different colour to indicate them as mandatory.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim msg As String
Dim val As Integer
Dim i As Integer

val = Cells(2, "B").Value

 For i = 11 To 11 + val

  If IsEmpty(Cells(2, i).Value) Then
     msg = "please enter name"
    End If

  Next i
End Sub
```

The above code is not working.

Correct me.
Thank you.

Next question...

Every time I Have to click on this macro to get  such message right...
Instead of clicking on the macro.. Is it possible to get the error  message whenever i save the file or close the file if the fields are not filled??

Comment: Along with the message issue, it looks like you got confused about the `Cells` syntax: `Cells(2, i)` refers to row 2 and column i, not row i and column 2.

Comment: Ya, i got confused with the rows and columns.
Thank u Rory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `msg` string, but you're not producing it to the user.  Also you are doing nothing to colour the cells.

```
If (IsEmpty(Cells(2, i).Value)) Then
    MsgBox("Please fill in " & i & " fields.")
End if
```

And for colouring:

```
Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

### Update

If you want to avoid having to click a button to check the cells, you can user `Worksheet_Change` and only look at the values you're interested in.  This will show the MsgBox every time you change one of the values if any of them are empty:

```
Private Function RangeContains(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
    Dim intersects
    Set intersects = Application.intersect(range1, range2)
    RangeContains = Not intersects Is Nothing
End Function

Private Function GetColumnLetter(number As Integer)
    GetColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, number).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' This is the "11" in your question - adjust to suit
    Const offset As Integer = 11

    ' This is the address of the first cell you want to check - adjust to suit
    Dim firstCell As String
    firstCell = GetColumnLetter(offset) & "2"

    ' This is the number of cells you want to check (the number in your B2 cell)
    Dim numCells As Integer
    numCells = Int(Cells(2, "B").Value)

    ' This is the last cell you want to check
    Dim lastCell As String
    lastCell = GetColumnLetter(offset + numCells) & "2"

    ' This is the range that contains all the cells you want to check
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(firstCell, lastCell)

    ' This is a boolean flag used to determine if we need to display the MsgBox or not
    Dim valid As Boolean
    valid = True

    ' This is our iterator for looping through the range
    Dim cell

    ' Reset the background color of our range
    myRange.Interior.Color = vbWhite

    ' If the cell that was changed (Target) is inside our range, we need to do the check
    If (RangeContains(myRange, Target)) Then
        ' Check for empty values
        For Each cell In myRange
            If (IsEmpty(cell.Value)) Then
                ' This cell is inside our range but is empty.  Change its background
                ' Color to Red and prompt to show a message
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                valid = False
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    If Not valid Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in red fields"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
This is not verifying if the cells are empty..
I have non-empty cells (b11.b12,b13) and empty cells b14,b15,b16  where val=6.
This msg is displayed for all the fields, whereas it shd display only for b14,15,16

Comment: Sorry, left off `.Value`

Comment: Every time I Have to click on this macro to get  such message right...
Instead of clicking on the macro.. Is it possible to get the error  message whenever i save the file or close the file if the fields are not filled??

Comment: You currently have it as a handler for `CommandButton1_Click`.  You *could* make it a handler for something else, like perhaps `Worksheet_Change` but if you did that, I would suggest removing the `MsgBox` and just setting the background colour - otherwise you'd have message boxes showing up all the time.

Comment: ok, but the msg is mandatory for the user to fill the empty boxes. is there any way?

Comment: If the values are mandatory and provided by the user, you should have some form of validation run before you do anything with the data.  EG: You could give the cells default values to begin with and when the user changes the value, check that it is a valid value or cancel the change.

Comment: The values are not predefined(So data validation doesnt come into pic).. they are strings.. they could be anything the user want to enter.

Comment: @sai  Updated.  Hopefully this helps you.  Remember, it's not meant to be perfect - its meant to help you work out a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i%, cl As Range
i = 0
For Each cl In Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(2, 11 + Cells(2, "B").Value))
    If cl.Value = "" Then
        cl.Interior.Color = vbRed
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cl

If i > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Mondatory fields (" & i & ") not filled yet!"
ElseIf i = 1 Then
    MsgBox "One mandatory field has not been filled yet!"
End If
End sub
```